# MySQLi UPDATE query not working properly

Tags: php, database, mysqli, sql-update

My SQLi UPDATE query doesn't seem to be working, I have tried almost everything and I don't know where I am going wrong. I created a similar style PHP but for registering a person (using INSERT) and that worked fine. Here is my UPDATE code:

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

    $firstname= $_POST["firstname"];
    $surname = $_POST["surname"];
    $info= $_POST["info"];

    $statement = mysqli_prepare("UPDATE `People` SET `firstname`=? , `surname`=? , `info`=? WHERE `personid`=79 ");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "sss", $firstname, $surname, $info);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_close($statement);
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: In yr query there are four params to bind, but you bind only three parameters (missing id).

Comment: [Enabling PHP errors](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1053424/660921) might help.

Comment: Missing ID for `WHERE `personid`=?`